How to make Windows Desktop icon size stay permanent?
At some point I needed to resize the (Windows) desktop icons.
So I adjusted the relevant windows registry items, for both icon size and spacing, as widely described elsewhere. Specifically:
# Icon Spacing:
# HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
# Type in a value between -480 to -2730
IconSpacing         -1400
IconVerticalSpacing -1400

# Desktop Icon size:
# HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop 
# Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop
# IconSize 0x20  (32)
IconSize 0x18

(I have no idea why MS is incapable to provide a Settings option for this!?)
However, after a Windows update and reboot, the desktop icons came up completely jumbled.
I checked the registry items and they were intact.
So I resized the desktop icons using [CTRL] + <mouse scroll up/down> (while pointer on empty desktop area), after a few scrolls, suddenly the correct icon layout was re-instated.
Great, but after reboot, they were all jumbled up again!
What's going on, and how can I make my current desktop icon size and layout, permanent?


After resizing desktop icons, right click on desktop and select Refresh.

This should save the desktop layout.


If this doesn't work,

Open Notepad, enter anything in the text editor, and then shut down the computer without saving the work.
When asked to confirm, click on Cancel. This will prevent Windows from logging off and save the desktop icon arrangement.

Source: 3 Ways to Save Your Desktop Icon Position Layout on Windows 11.

I need more info. What is really going on under the hood? For example, what is saving it and where is it saved? (I have 2 desktop.ini files showing on my desktop, but when I go into CMD/posh I only see 1, when I do ls/dir.) Also, I noticed their content didn't change after changing registry and having the correct desktop showing. I would, ultimately, like to restore this programmatically using powershell, and/or C#. The DesktopOK program seem to do something different, and it's not open source, so would rather try to do this myself.

@not2qubit edit your question to include the above comment and add the contents of desktop.ini files to it as well. maybe someone will be able to help
